# Pop vector of int from vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have `vector<vector<int> > tchSubVec`.

I don't understand why I can't execute this line: `vector<int>& vec = tchSubVec[i];`.

Also I don't get any suggestions from the IDE when putting `.` at the end of `tchSubVec[i]`.

here is the full code:

```
 for(vector<vector<int> >::iterator i = tchSubVec.begin(); i < tchSubVec.end(); i++)
    {
        cout << "Subjects of teacher " << distance(tchSubVec.begin(), i) << " : \n";
        vector<int>& vec = tchSubVec[i];
        for(vector<int>::iterator j =  vec.begin(); j < vec->end(); j++)
        {
            cout << vec[i] << ", ";
        }
    }
```

what is wrong with the code?

Comment: Do we really need 4 answers telling exactly the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a misunderstanding between iterators and `operator[]`. You can not use an iterator with `operator[]`. To get the value the iterator points to you need to use the de-reference operator (`operator*`).

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<int> >::iterator iter;
iter begin = tchSubVec.begin();
iter end = tchSubVec.end();
for(iter it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
    cout << "Subjects of teacher " << distance(begin, it) << " : \n";
    vector<int>& vec = *it;
    typedef std::vector<int>::iterator iter2;
    iter2 end2 = vec.end();
    for(iter2 it2 = vec.begin(); it2 != end2; ++it2) {
        cout << *it2 << ", ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An `::iterator` is not the same as an index. You can't use the iterator inside the `[]` operator. Instead, simply dereference it. This works because the iterator has the `*` operator overloaded.

```
for(vector<vector<int> >::iterator i = tchSubVec.begin(); i < tchSubVec.end(); i++) {
    vector<int>& vec = *i;
}
```

Btw., if you can use C++11, it eases iteration so much:

```
for (auto &vec : tchSubVec) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `i` is a `vector<vector<int>>::iterator`, not a `size_t` (unsigned integer).

Either use iterators:

```
vector<int>& vec = *i;
/* or just use i directly, like:
   for (vector<int>::iterator j = i->begin(); j != i->end(); ++j)
*/
```

Or use indexes:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < tchSubVec.size(); ++i) {
    vector<int>& vec = tchSubVec[i];
```

But you can't mix them.

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<int>& vec = tchSubVec[i];
```

You're mixing up two concepts:  index addressing and iterators.  They are related but not the same, and not interchangeable.

`i` here is an `iterator`, which is used in a way similar to a pointer.  It's as if you're doing this:

```
char** bufs = new char* [256];
for (size_t i = 0; i : 256; ++i)
  bufs[i] = new char [1024];

/// ... then ...

for (char** it = bufs; it < bufs+256; ++it)
  char* buf = bufs[it];
  //              ^^^^
```

Note here that `it` is a `char**`, not an integral.  You use integrals with indexing, not pointers.

What you actually want to do is *dereference* the iterator:

```
vector<int>& vec = *i;
```